# WSO2IS 5.8, adding email OTP template error while sending email Resource does not exist at path /_system/config/identity/config/emailTemplate

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have configured email otp in axis2.xml
I can also see in from the wso2is Console.
Updated it through console as well.
I still get this error when wso2is trying to send email:

```
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/config/identity/config/emailTemplate
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:532)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getGhostResourceFromCache(CacheBackedRegistry.java:225)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:198)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Also in looking at the registry in wso2is console I see that path as:

```
/_system/config/identity/email
```

Which is different from what the code is expecting?

Please let me know if anyone has seen this error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems like the emailOTP emailTemplate file does not exists in the registry. Browse the registry by moving into **Registry>Browse** and Navigate to the  **/_system/config/identity/email**. Verify whether you could see **emailotp** template there.

Sometime you might have added the emailtemplate in the email-admin-config.xml configuration file. But It might not be added to the registry.

If the template does not exist in registry, Refer this blog for how to add email template via the management console. http://www.securityinternal.com/2016/08/email-templates-in-identity-management.html

Comment: Thanks for you response.

Comment: I went and updated and hit save again through the management console. I can see it in email template EmailOTP, but in the registry it is showing in the following path:    /_system/config/identity/email/emailotp but I still see the error that the resource does not exist at:  /_system/config/identity/config/emailTemplate
seems like the path is different in where it wants to look for email template??

Comment: ok It worked when I changed from gmailOTP to local wso2is OTP. so it had problem sending email through gmail. Although it still gives the same exception that it cannot find the emailtemplate resource, it ignores and goes ahead with the execution. Some thing to clean up I guess.  Not sure what I am missing but the html in email is showing the email conent with html in outlook, how do I change that to treat it as html email